# "diary for the coming year"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

This is an excerption from an invitation email template:

> We meet on Wednesday evenings during term time. We would be honored if
>   you would accept this invitation to join us on a Wednesday evening.
>   **Our diary** for the coming year is still quite flexible, but the most
>   ideal dates for us would be ...

I looked up the dictionary and there are two meanings for the word "diary".

1. (North American English datebook) a book with spaces for each day of the year in which you can write down things you have to do in the future
2. a book in which you can write down the experiences you have each day, your private thoughts, etc.

I reckon the bold "diary" fits definition 1 best. But I wonder if it a typical use of diary this word. If it were me, I would choice "schedule" or "plan".

```
Our schedule for the coming year is still quite flexible...
Our plan for the coming year is still quite flexible
```

Answer (score 3):

This use of "diary" seems to be more or less exclusively BrE.  You just needed to have checked the British dictionaries:

> [**diary**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diary) (n):  (British) A book with spaces for each day of the year in which one notes **appointments** or information.

In AmE, we would be more likely to use *appointment book*, *engagement book*, *calendar*, *schedule*, or in some cases *daybook* or *agenda*.

Comment: But  I also want to ask if the sentence "Our diary for the coming year is still quite flexible" sounds natural. Would you prefer to put it as "Our schedule for the coming year is still quite flexible"? or other words instead of "diary"

Comment: @chika  As I said, this use of "diary" is quite British.  Being American, it sounds odd to me, but if a British person said it, I would assume it's perfectly natural.  It's just dialect, as there are many American words for things that the British generally don't use, like *truck*, *apartment*, and *elevator* (respectively *lorry, flat*, and *lift* in the UK).